# Center the activity indicator when having navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I cannot center the activity indicator with respect to height. It was fine before I added a Navigation controller and after that it is center horizontally but not vertically. Here's the photo and the code.

[image: picture]

Here's the code to center when there was no navigation controller.

```
_loadingView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:_loadingView];
```

Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: try inside **-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated** `_loadingView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, (self.view.frame.size.height - navigationBarHeight - tabBarHeight) / 2.0);`

Comment: try this  CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
   CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    
    
    _loadingView.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2.0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - navigationBarHeight - tabBarHeight) / 2.0)

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. It's same as before.

Comment: Tried both. It's still same as before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11587513/4831524 check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
_loadingView.center = self.navigationController.view.center;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_loadingView];
```

it's different view

Answer (score 1):

The `UIViewController`'s view reports its `center` coordinate in its parent's coordinate space, which is why it's vertically offset by the height of the navigation bar.

If you want to place the indicator in a similar fashion as you're doing right now, calculate the center coordinate yourself:

`CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0)
_loadingView.center = center;
[self.view addSubview:_loadingView];`

Be sure to update this whenever the main view's bounds change, i.e. in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` as mentioned in another answer.

However, this could all be updated and simplified by adopting [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) and setting two center constraints, one for each axis. You can do so either in Interface Builder mode or in code, check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way And please check below link also

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {    

    _loadingView.center = self.view.center; 

}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587804/5184217

Comment: Nope! It got more down instead of getting up.

Answer (score 0):

**It will help you to resolve your problem**

```
_loadingView = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, (self.view.frame.size.height - navigationBarHeight - tabBarHeight) / 2.0)

[self.view addSubview:_loadingView];
```

Comment: Yes I tried this one too, got from this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11587804/5184217

and didn't work either.

Comment: you have to minus your navigation bar height from indicator frame.

Comment: Indicator frame? Any code for it? I am new to it so don't know much yet.

Comment: @mustafaHassan I edited now. Copy this line of code to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check under top bars in Attribute inspector for your navigation controller and view controller.

[image]